# ref() not getting bean config for nested map value using spring dsl on grails

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, dsl

On **Grails 2.3.7**, trying to set a nested map value using bean reference in `resources.groovy`

```
   msgbean(Message){
      text = 'hello'
   }

   bean1(ConfigObj){
      prop = [ref('msgbean')]
   }

   bean2(ConfigObj){
      prop = [key: ref('msgbean')]
   }

   bean3(ConfigObj){
      prop = [key:[msg:ref('msgbean')]]
   }
```

`bean1` and `bean2` get wired correctly,

```
  println '1 ' + bean.prop[0].text
  println '2 ' + bean2.prop['key'].text
```

prints...

```
1 hello
2 hello
```

`bean3`, however, doesn't get its reference to `msgbean`...

```
println '3 ' + bean3.prop['key']['msg'].text

Error |
No such property: text
```

Taking a closer look, `bean3.prop['key']['msg']` ends up with not `Message`, but  an instance of `RuntimeBeanReference`, with `beanName=<msgbean>`; so I tried invoking `getSource()` on it, returns null, which can happen [according](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.2/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/RuntimeBeanReference.html#getSource%28%29) to docs (not ok for me)

Why does `ref()` not work for nested maps?

**Alternate: Inline DSL Config**

Something like this would be nice too; is this possible? Gave it a shot, returned a closure which, when executed, returns 'hello'; no surprise there, but not what I want; need the `Message` instance instead.

```
bean3(ConfigObj){
      prop = [key:[msg:{Message -> {
                          text = 'hello'
                       }
               ]]
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get `RuntimeBeanReference`s unwrapped automatically at runtime the Map configured in the spring context needs to be a `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ManagedMap` - the spring DSL automatically converts any map that contains a `RuntimeBeanReference` value into a `ManagedMap` but it only does this at one level deep, it doesn't look inside maps of maps etc.

A bit messy but you could declare the inner map as a top-level bean in its own right:

```
bean3Message(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean) {
   sourceMap = [msg:ref('msgbean')]
}

bean3(ConfigObj){
   prop = [key:ref('bean3Message')]
}
```

Now the maps both contain runtime references at the first level, so will both be "managed" correctly.

Comment: Ian, if `MapFactoryBean` supports one level deep, what benefit do they provide over simple maps that support he same? Can I assign a map value using inline config? (see my update).

Comment: @raffian It's nothing specific to `MapFactoryBean` - the DSL will convert to a `ManagedMap` _any_ Map that is assigned to a bean property and that contains at least one RuntimeBeanReference as a value.  It's not the fact that I'm using a `MapFactoryBean` that is relevant here, it's the fact that I'm defining a named bean (`bean3Message` or `bean3`) that has a property (`sourceMap` or `prop`) whose value is a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that works for me:

```
bean3(ConfigObj) {
    prop = [key : ref(bean3Message(org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MapFactoryBean) {
            sourceMap = [msg:ref('msgbean')]
    })]
}
```

It's messy too, but you don't have to spread the map definition across multiple top-level beans.

I've tried this with list (using org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ListFactoryBean with the attribute sourceList instead of sourceMap).